# What is the max depth allowed in Random Forest? I am using Spark ML

Tags: pyspark, random-forest, apache-spark-ml, depth

I am using Spark ML. Need to know the max depth allowed?

Random Forest
Maximum limit

I know the default is 5 but want to know till what extend I can go

Answer (score 0):

The [sourcecode](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/RandomForestClassifier.scala) tells us that maxDepth is an Int. You can get the max value of an Int in Scala by calling:

```
Int.MaxValue
```

Output:

```
Int = 2147483647
```

but, it is restricted in the [implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ca6955858cec868c878a2fd8528dbed0ef9edd3f/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/tree/impl/RandomForest.scala#L137) to =<30.

Comment: I read somewhere that the max depth they allow is 30 right now. That post was from 2017. I am not sure if they have increased that in next versions.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't checked the randomtree implementation. 30 is still the upper limit. I have updated my post.

Comment: @style realistically speaking, using that high of a depth would not be recommended. Unless you're dealing with extremely high dimensional data, you'd most likely end up overfitting.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: The rows are in billions but I have less features...not many. Any suggestion how can one play around with deeper  using only 1/2 tree.

Comment: @pault In `sklearn` the depth of my model's trees go up to 3000. 30 is too little for `spark`, unless the definition of `spark`'s depth and `sklearn`'s depth differ.